# Mysql SUM And Group from multiple tables but only with certain data

Tags: mysql

I have 3 database tables as follows:

## projects:

`id`

`project_name`

`project_location`

`status`

## project_expenses

`id`

`project_id`

`expense_category`

`expense_subcategory`

`amount`

`userid`

`date`

`payment_status`

`project_status`

## project_income

`id`

`project_id`

`project_income`

`date`

`userid`

`project_status`

projects.id, project_expenses.project_id and project_income.project_id are related.

I need to create a query displaying **Project_ID,Project_Name,SUM of Project_Income,SUM of Project_expenses, Difference**

I tried the following query.

```
SELECT p.id AS id, p.project_name AS project_name
,(SELECT SUM(i.project_income)
FROM project_income i
WHERE i.project_id = p.id 
)AS income,
(SELECT SUM(e.amount)
FROM project_expenses e
WHERE e.project_id = p.id 
)AS expenses,
(SELECT (income - expenses)) AS difference
FROM projects p
WHERE p.status = 'Active'
```

BUT some "**projects without any income and expenses**" are also listed. I need to display only those projects with expenses and incomes.

How is that possible. Requesting help...

Comment: What about projects with expenses but no income or income but no expenses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT projects.id AS id, 
       projects.project_name AS project_name, 
       SUM(totals.income) income, 
       SUM(totals.expenses) expenses,
       SUM(totals.income) - SUM(totals.expenses) difference
FROM ( SELECT SUM(project_income) income,
              0 expenses,
              project_id
       FROM project_income i
       GROUP BY project_id
     UNION ALL
       SELECT 0,
              SUM(e.amount),
              project_id
       FROM project_expenses e
       GROUP BY project_id ) totals
JOIN projects ON totals.project_id = projects.id
WHERE projects.status = 'Active'
GROUP BY projects.id, 
         projects.project_name
```

Projects which have at least one income and/or expence will be listed only.

Comment: You need to add group by after where condition

Comment: @Mansi Yes, edited. Thanks. At first, I forgot about the last grouping at all...

Comment: @Akina I need to add the difference between income & expenses too ??

Comment: @Pamela Do not use output aliases, they're not available in this place. Code updated.